# PHP result display in textbox onClick

Tags: php

I need to get result where PHP generated ID for current button click is displayed in html textfield...

Is there any easy way of doing this?

This is the link of what I am trying to do http://dtech.id.lv/lat.php
When user first comes he doesn't have code, so he clicks get code.
I need that php generated code is pasted in textbox after this click...

Could someone help?
Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is: Use AJAX. A more specific answer could be provided if you posted your code.

Comment: what u have done still?? show the code

Comment: You need to show some code and provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do.  Is the ID already available in the button, or does the button click request the value back from the server?  You will need to do some basic reading on Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button clicked, something shows in the text field. Sometimes Javascript isn't necessary.

```
<?php
$code = "";
if (isset($_POST['buttonId']))
{
    $code = 'Some code here';   
}
?>
<form method="post" >
    <input name="textField" id="textField" type="text" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" />
    <input name="buttonId" id="buttonId" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What if `$code` is undefined? What if `$code` contains characters that will break the HTML output?

Comment: I was assuming he had control over $code here and it wasn't user generated. There's also another hundred "what if" questions you could ask but they're out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html looks like this:

```
<button id="myPHPid">...</button>
<input type="text" id="idRecipient" />
```

then

```
<button id="myPHPid" onclick="document.getElementById('idRecipient').value = this.id">...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try  this code

```
$('button').live('click',function() {
    var $butVal= $(this).val();
    alert($butVal);
    $('input#buttonValue').val($butVal);
    return false;
});
```

### [live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JTrJV/)